# call relationship in laravel blade

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 3 table as mentioned below.

Table 1(users):

```
|id    |name  |keterangan |role_id |provinsi_id   |
```

Table 2(roles):

```
|id  |name  |description |
```

Table 3(provinsis)

```
|id |name |description  |
```

user model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function provinsi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Provinsi::class);
    }

}
```

role model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    //
    

}
```

provinsi model

```
class Provinsi extends Model
{
    

}
```

user controller

```
class UserController extends Controller{
  public function index()
    {
        //$users = User::latest()->paginate(5);
         $users = User::with(['role', 'provinsi'])->latest()->paginate(5);
  
        return view('users.index',compact('users'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
}
```

index.blade

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
               <tr>
                   <td>{{ $user->nama }}</td>
                   <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                   <td>{{ $user->nip_lama }}</td>
                   <td>{{ $user->role->name}}</td>
                   <td>{{ $user->provinsi->name}}</td
                 </tr>
  @endforeach
```

how to get role name and provinsi name in index.blade, because that code wil result
like this in table html:

```
<td>{"id":4,"name":"Change Agent","description":null, "created_at":null,"updated_at":null}</td>
```

and this

```
<td>{"id":2,"name":"Gorontalo","description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null} </td>
```

note: that json already return the corecct roles and provinsi but the result i want simply

```
 <td>admin</td>
 <td>gorontalo</td>
```

i've tried php artisan tinker, and its return Change Agent/Gorontalo whenever i call
$user->provinsi->name

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach relations to the model in the controller.

```
class UserController extends Controller{
  public function index()
    {
        //
        $users = User::with(['role', 'provinsi')->latest()->paginate(5);
  
        return view('users.index',compact('users'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: $users = User::with(['role', 'provinsi'])->latest()->paginate(5);

it still get error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\sipmanner-app\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

when i call  <td>{{ $user->role->name}}</td>

Comment: Try again after defining the reverse relations.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, you are missing some braces.

```
  <td>{{ $user->provinsi->name</td>
```

Should be

```
  <td>{{ $user->role->name}}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->provinsi->name}}</td>
```

Did you find that?